# Plot variable number of lines/curves with bokeh

Tags: pandas, bokeh

I generate pandas dataframe with many "y" columns (y1, y2, y3...) and one "x" column. The x-column is always the same. I wish to plot all these x-y lines/curves on the same graph.

Can I make it such that bokeh plots the number of lines as a function of how many "y" columns are in my dataframe? Such that the plotting part of the script is not dependent on a fixed number of "y" columns and can work with any dataframe with 'n' # of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'x'  : [1,2,3],
  'y0' : [1,3,2],
  'y1' : [2,1,3],
})

colors = ['red', 'blue']

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(plot_height=250)

i = 0
for name in df.columns:
    if not name.startswith('y'): continue
    p.line('x', name, color=colors[i], source=source)
    i += 1

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: One question: when I change from p.line to p.circle, and have 12 "y" columns with 7 points each (expecting 84 points in the plot), I only see the points occuring at x = 0. Any idea why this is, and why all of the points aren't showing?

Comment: Also, when I try to add a legend using the below lines, the plot does not produce it ( whether I use p.line or p.circle).
`p.legend.location = "top_left"

p.legend.click_policy="hide"
`

Comment: Please post new topics for new questions. Stringing Q and A over the comments makes this site much harder for laters users to follow.